# How can I use a while loop (or any loop) within a custom function in ARM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am trying to solve a problem where I have a counter that goes from 10 to 50. For each number, I must check if it is a multiple of 8 (if it is, then I store 0xffff in R3), or if it is a multiple of 3 (and I would store 0xbbbb) or if it is a multiple of both (where I store 0xffbb in R3).

For checking if the number is a multiple of 3, my plan is to subtract 3 from the number until it either reaches 0 or is less than 3. I am struggling to figure out how I can use a loop within a custom function. Here is my code so far:

```
.section    .data
.balign 4
return_start:   .word 0
.balign 4
return_loop:    .word 0
.balign 4
return_8:   .word 0
.balign 4
return_3:   .word 0
.balign 4
return_3loop:   .word 0

.section    .text

.global _start
/* .func   _loop
.func   _multOf8
.func   _multOf3 */

_start:
    LDR R1, addr_return_start
    STR lr, [R1]

    mov r0, #10 /* Start with 10 */
    BL  _loop

    LDR lr, addr_return_start
    LDR lr, [LR]

_loop:
    add R0, #1  /* increment by 1 */
    MOV r3, #0 /* resetting r3 */
    CMP R0, #50 /* check if it is 50, if it is then go to the end */
    BEQ _end

    /* else check if it is a multple of 8 */
    BL  _multOf8
    /* check if it is a multiple of 3 */
    BL  _multOf3

    B   _loop

_multOf8:
    /* save LR */
    LDR R1, addr_return_8
    STR lr, [R1]

    AND r1, r0, #7
    CMP r1, #0
    MOVEQ r3, #0xffff   /* if it is a multiple of 8 */
    /* else return */
    LDR LR, addr_return_8
    LDR LR, [LR]
    BX LR

_multOf3:
    LDR R1, addr_return_3
    STR lr, [R1]

    /* if it is a multiple of 3 */
    /* will need to subtract it continuously? */
    PUSH R0
    BL  _3loop
    POP R0

    LDR LR, addr_return_3
    LDR LR, [lr]
    BX  lr

_3loop:
    LDR R1, addr_return_3loop
    STR lr, [R1]

_end:   B   _end

addr_return_start:  .word return_start

addr_return_loop:   .word return_loop

addr_return_8:  .word return_8

addr_return_3:  .word return_3

addr_return_3loop:  .word return_3loop
```

As you can see, in the function `_multOf3` I am attempting to branch off to `_3loop`. The issue is, that I do not know what to do with `LR` and how to return from this loop. I feel like if I was to store LR, it would continuously be overwritten each time we iterate through the loop.

Any help would be much appreciated! Please do note that I am a beginner in ARM Assembly.

Comment: `LDR R1, addr_return_3loop`, `STR lr, [R1]` what on Earth that suppose to mean at first place ? `PUSH R0`, `BL  _3loop` why to push `R0` if it's not used in  `_3loop` ? "I do not know what to do with LR and how to return from this loop", return after `bl func_addr` is `bx lr`.

Comment: ```LDR R1, addr_return_3loop 
   STR lr, [R1]
```
This is to store the return address. I am following this tutorial: youtube.com/watch?v=2ghL_R5CSaI

As for pushing and popping R0, that is just temporary and has nothing to do with the problem right now. I was just in the process of testing things. It has not been used in _3loop because the function is currently incomplete as I am unsure on how to return. 

I understand that ```bx lr``` is used to return, but I am confused as to how to manage ```LR``` in this case.

Comment: why do you want to **save** `lr` at first place, what is the purpose of that ? if you don't change `lr`, return right away. You don't need to 'manage' it in such case

Comment: Ah I see, I will give that a shot. I am not sure why I want to save ```lr``` as I am currently following tutorials and doing as they advise. I'll experiment with different methods though to see if any of them work. I'll try using ```bx lr``` from the while loop in that case.

Comment: first off create the algorithm, ideally in a language you know.  then convert that to the new language (assembly in this case).  use the arm documentation for the instructions, is there a reason to use tutorials?

Comment: It's better to store the return address using ```PUSH``` and ```POP``` on ```lr```

Answer (score 1):

Loops in ARM aren't too complicated. There's a couple ways to achieve one. Generally you'll need to set aside one register as a loop counter. The example below is for a decrementing loop.

```
_loop: /* R2 is the loop counter */

/* do stuff here */

subs R2,R2,#1   /* the S at the end sets the flags accordingly. If the result is zero,
                   the zero flag will be set and BNE will not branch.
BNE _loop
/* if R2 = 0, execution will fall through to here, otherwise it jumps back to the loop's start
```

An incrementing loop takes an extra step, since you'll need to compare the value of the loop counter to the desired endpoint:

```
_loop /* R2 is the loop counter */

/* do stuff here */

add R2,R2,#1   /* no need for S at the end, it does us no good here. */
CMP R2,#50     /* 50 was arbitrarily chosen for this example. */
BNE _loop      /* this just checks if they're not equal, for this example it's sufficient but 
               it's better to use BLS for signed numbers or BLO/BCC for unsigned */
```